# IE 11 issue with flexbox item with max-width

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

In IE 11 when an item items don't properly center if they have maximum width property. This example however works in Chrome and Firefox.

**[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/riloravopu/7/edit)**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red">non centered box</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a question somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a bug. But according to [**IE Feedback**](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/951267/horizontal-scrolling-with-flex-grow-max-width) it was supposed to be fixed already.

As a workaround, you can remove `flex-grow: 1;` if you don't have to use it.

Comment: They said only fixed in Edge, and at the time, they didn't care about IE besides security, and forgot about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really bugged me.

Answer (score 4):

Explicitly set `width: calc(100%);` so IE knows the box width and center it properly.

Comment: Why use calc() here?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue as well. In my case I wanted `flex-grow` but still wanted to limit the `max-width`. What I do is wrap any css I don't want IE11 to see in @support. IE11 does not support this rule and ignores its contents completely. I will just check for something that has been around forever like text-align so all the other modern browsers can apply the css rule. You can do this for anything, I just discovered this while trying to figure out an answer to this issue.

```
@supports(text-align:center) {
    div {
        max-width: 350px;
    }
}
```

Comment: So this says, "If I am IE, do not apply max-width", if you still want to limit the max-width (also in IE, presumably), how does this work for IE, which does support max-width? I'm not understanding the example here I think hehe :)

Comment: @SidOfc IE does not support `@supports()` so it skips over any css rules inside it. `text-align:center` is an arbitrary css rule that is supported in all browsers. So browsers that can use `@supports ` will apply the code, IE will not.

Comment: Ahh right, just showing an arbitrary line of CSS to explain how you could make IE skip certain styles, cheers for the clarification!